# Has the color scheme changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I am not seeing an announcement anywhere, but it sure seems like the color scheme has changed to a bunch of Orange text?  Is this new?  Or do I have a lousy memory?

Is there a reason for orange?  Orange is a pretty odd color choice IMHO.

Comment: Please post screenshots showing what you think has changed as it will help people understand.

Comment: Shortly after I asked this I saw it as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a bug that they are working on fixing as we speak.

[Why did all sites turn orange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367641/why-did-all-sites-turn-orange)

It it appears to have been fixed and reverted back to the correct colors.